# Node.js service is unable to connect with Mysql using docker composer

Tags: mysql, node.js, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to run 2 Node.js and 2 mysql services with docker composer, both of Node.js services are unable to connect with Mysql services while I was able to login into both Mysql containers with respective credentials.
Node.js service giving the following error:

**original: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.22.0.2:3308**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxEUP.png)

I have also successfully connected a PHP script with both of the MySQL services.

My docker-composer file :

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  genreapp:
    depends_on:
      - genresqldb
    build: ./genre
    #command: sh -c './wait-for-it.sh -t 0 genresqldb:$DB_PORT_GENRE'
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file: ./.env
    links:
      - genresqldb
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
    ports:
      - $NODE_PORT_GENRE:$NODE_PORT_GENRE
    environment:
      - DB_USERNAME=$DB_USERNAME
      - DB_PASSWORD=$DB_PASSWORD_GENRE
      - DB_NAME=$DB_NAME_GENRE
      - DB_PORT=$DB_PORT_GENRE
      - DIALTEC=$DIALTEC
      - APP_PORT=$NODE_PORT_GENRE
      - HOST=$HOST
      - DB_HOST_GENRE=genresqldb
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
  movieapp:
    depends_on:
      - moviesqldb
    build: ./movie
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file: ./.env
    links:
      - moviesqldb
    volumes:
    - ./:/app
    #command: sh -c './wait-for-it.sh -t 0 moviesqldb:$DB_PORT_MOVIE'
    ports:
      - $NODE_PORT_MOVIE:$NODE_PORT_MOVIE
    environment:
      - DB_USERNAME=$DB_USERNAME
      - DB_PASSWORD=$DB_PASSWORD_MOVIE
      - DB_NAME=$DB_NAME_MOVIE
      - DB_PORT=$DB_PORT_MOVIE
      - DIALTEC=$DIALTEC
      - APP_PORT=$NODE_PORT_MOVIE
      - HOST=$HOST
      - DB_HOST_GENRE=moviesqldb
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
  genresqldb:
    image: mysql:5
    # restart: unless-stopped
    env_file: ./.env
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=$DB_PASSWORD_GENRE
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=$DB_NAME_GENRE
    expose:
      - $DB_PORT_GENRE
    ports:
      - $DB_PORT_GENRE:$DB_PORT
    volumes:
      - db:/var/lib/mysqli
  moviesqldb:
    image: mysql:5
    # restart: unless-stopped
    env_file: ./.env
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=$DB_PASSWORD_MOVIE
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=$DB_NAME_MOVIE
    expose:
      - $DB_PORT_MOVIE
    ports:
      - $DB_PORT_MOVIE:$DB_PORT
    volumes:
      - db:/var/lib/mysqli
volumes:
  db:
```

Comment: MySQL normally listens on port 3306, not 3308, and you should fix that port number in your `$DB_PORT_GENRE` environment variable.

Comment: $DB_PORT_GENRE hold 3308 port while $DB_PORT hold 3306 value in environment variable.

Comment: You're telling the `genreapp` to connect to `DB_PORT=$DB_PORT_GENRE`, which is 3308, but it needs to connect to the standard MySQL port 3306.

Comment: have a Look at  my env File : 

HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD_GENRE=pass@4500$
DB_PASSWORD_MOVIE=password@4500$$
DB_NAME_GENRE=homitags_genre
DB_NAME_MOVIE=homitags_movie
DB_PORT_GENRE=3306
DB_PORT_MOVIE=3308
DIALTEC=mysql
NODE_PORT_GENRE=6868
NODE_PORT_MOVIE=8080

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just by using Version 3 resolve the  issue.